# MySQL query with multiple BETWEEN is always NULL

Tags: mysql, between

Maybe I'm missing the obvious here, but why is this query always NULL?

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`viewer_count`),0) AS avg_viewer FROM `table` 
WHERE 
(id BETWEEN 1 AND 8) 
AND 
(id BETWEEN 26 AND 32)
```

Isn't it possible to get the average of multiple ranges like this?

Comment: How can a number be between 1 and 8 AND between 26 and 32? That's logically impossible, dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not possible for an `id` to be between 1 and 8 and at the same time between 26 and 32, the query is returning NULL as no rows were matched. If you use `OR` as squemeamish suggested in the comment, you will get the average over both ranges.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 1 AND 8   THEN `viewer_count` END),0) AS avg_viewer1_8
     , ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 26 AND 32 THEN `viewer_count` END),0) AS avg_viewer26_32
FROM `table`
```